# ASP.NET Core 6 with Swagger UI not working on IIS web server

Tags: c#, iis, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

My ASP.NET Core 6.0 site with Swagger UI returns "Page not found" error when published on IIS server.

I published my site to a folder (`D:\APIsite`) then set it to IIS. Tried debug and release configuration.

This is the code in `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(new MyOwnCompactJsonFormatter(), "API_Log.txt").CreateLogger();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<CheckPointMetraContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CheckPointPackagingContext>();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "ToDo API",
        Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
    });

});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger(c => { c.SerializeAsV2 = true; });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseRouting();

Log.Logger.Information("API http://localhost:5139/swagger/index.html");

app.Run();
```

Config in `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31124",
      "sslPort": 44300
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "TestApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
     
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7003;http://localhost:5139",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

IIS Site bindings

```
http   5139 127.0.0.1
https  7003 127.0.0.1
```

Folder to app D:\APIsite

When entering site the authorization part works fine, but then page not found error.

When debugging or release first page URL is https://localhost:7003/index.html (All works fine)

When opening in IIS the first page URL is https://127.0.0.1:7003 (page not found after authorization)

Even if I ask for the correct URL from debug, I get "Page not found".

Another ASP.NET app works fine on IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it.
The first problem was in my LaunchSettings.json. applicationUrl must be the same as in IIS Bindings. so if in IIS i had 127.0.0.1 then in my launchsettings i had to write 127.0.0.1.
The second was in program.cs.
I should have turn

```
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger(c => { c.SerializeAsV2 = true; });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
    }
```

to this

```
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

So without any Condition if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())